# How to calculate mean value for each column ignoring NA

Tags: r, data.table, mean

table, data.frame.

Which has 12 columns with variable names and 24 rows `df`

Like:

```
Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var12
1     NA   2     3    4
5     6    2     3    3
NA    7    8     NA   4
```

And I want to calculate the mean for each column while ignoring the Na's
For example:

`colMeans(df)`

And get the result like:

```
Var1  Var2  Var3  Var4  Var12
 3     6,5   4     3     3,66
```

I don't want the `NA`'s to be considered in the calculation of Mean.

I tried some methods like `na.omit`, `!is.na`, but I don't get the desired result like what I described above.

Comment: `colMeans(df, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: Yeah that worked ! Thanx was so easy.. :P

Comment: You might wanna post it as answer?

Comment: The calculation of Means is correct but how can I get it like horizontal while getting the col names above each mean number?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. Can you update the post with the expected output?

Comment: Yeah In the expected output you can see what I want. Is each variable name from the column and below the mean value

Comment: It gives me the same expected output as shown when I do `colMeans(df, na.rm = TRUE)`, I have a variable name and it's mean value below it, not sure what is missing.

Comment: Yeah It gives A single variable name called "means" But I want the variable names of my Data table which are 12 and below each of the 12 variables to be the single mean value. Like Var1-> 3.32 Var2-> 4.55 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a `data.table` `dt`, that looks like this:

```
dt
   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var12
1:    1   NA    2    3     4
2:    5    6    2    3     3
3:   NA    7    8   NA     4
```

You can simply use `lapply()`:

```
dt[, lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm = TRUE)]
```

The result is:

```
   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4    Var12
1:    3  6.5    4    3 3.666667
```

Comment: How would you syntax the exact thing but for row means?

Comment: You could use `dt[, apply(.SD, 1, mean, na.rm = TRUE)]`

Comment: for some reason now the dt[, lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm = TRUE)] gives me an error:Error in .subset(x, j) : invalid subscript type 'list'
But before I didnnt get an error?

Comment: oh ok I fixed it should have converted back to data table